# Is the operation $x*y=xy/(x+y+1)$ associative or not?

Tags: abstract-algebra, binary-operations, associativity

This questions is from Charles C. Pinter's "A Book Of Abstract Algebra, Second Edition". This is the 7th question of Chapter 2 on page 24.
In the selected answers section it says it is not associative but I have tried twice and keep on getting that it is associative.
The given answers are $(x*y)*z = xyz(x+y+1)/(x+y+z+xy+xz+yz+1)$ 
                  and $x*(y*z) = xyz(y+z+1)/(x+y+z+xy+xz+yz+1)$

My answer is $(x*y)*z = x*(y*z) = xyz/(x+y+z+xy+xz+yz+1)$

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Associative, note that $\ast$ is simply multiplication in disguise, since $$1+\frac{1}{x\ast y}=\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{y}\right).$$

Comment: But what is $0 \ast (-1)$?

Comment: Yes, you have to define your domain for this operation so that we know it is always defined.

Comment: By the way, you want $(x*y)*z=x*(y*z)$, not $(x*y)z=x(y*z)$.

Comment: I find the same result as you, so it seems associative.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews That's what he meant to say, but the formatting ate some of the asterisks. I edited them back in; you need to write `\*` instead of `*` in the code to make sure that it doesn't get read as *italics*.

Comment: Yeah sorry I did mean (x\*y)\*z and x\*(y\*z), also I should have mentioned that this is an operation on R. 
So this operation is associative then?

Comment: The author simplified wrongly the fractions: the terms $(x+y+1)$ and $(y+z+1)$ in the suggested results are spurious.

Comment: Ok thanks for the help.

Comment: The real problem is that the function is not well-defined for all $x,y$ real numbers. Binary operations need to be defined for them to be associative. You could say that they are associative whenever all values are defined...